# simple formula for det(AB-BA)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I was wondering whether there exists a simple formula for $\det(AB-BA)$, given two square matrices $A$ and $B$ with coefficients in a commutative ring.

Comment: For $2\times 2$ matrices over a field, for example, a matrix $C$ can be written as $AB-BA$ if and only if its trace is zero. So I doubt there is much you can do.

Comment: That seems wrong. If $n$ even and $A=B$, then $\det(0)\geq 2\det(A)^2$? @AlexSilva

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, that a matrix $C$ with trace zero can be wriiten as $C=AB - BA$ is true for genrral matrices not just $2 \times 2$. prof. kahan has proof on his web site.

Comment: Yeah, I guessed that, but I didn't know if for sure, and I had seen it proven recently for $2\times 2$ matrices. @abel

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, you are right!

Comment: Actually, for $2\times 2$ matrices, $[A,B]^2=\frac{1}{2}\mathrm{trace}[A,B]^2I$, so $\det([A,B])^2=\frac{1}{4}\left(\mathrm{trace}[A,B]^2\right)^2$. I don't know about anything useful for $n>2$.

Comment: Dear Thomas Andrews, thanks for your insight.